# Which is the stronger base?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base

I would like to know which of the two is the stronger base, tri-(n-butyl)amine or tri-(tert-butyl)amine?

I feel that the one with tert-butyl would be stronger as the inductive effect of tert-butyl on the nitrogen atom is stronger, making the nitrogen atom more electron-rich and better able to act as a base. This is because the carbon atoms in tri-(tert-butyl)amine are closer to the nitrogen atom, with the furthest carbon just 2 carbons away. However, for the other amine, the furthest carbon is 4 carbons away. I am not sure if my reasoning is flawed. Could someone clarify?

I am also not sure if steric hindrance is an important consideration here, considering the bulkiness of the tert-butyl substituent compared to the n-butyl substituent.

Also, pardon me if I had written the names of the chemicals wrongly.

Comment: Your reasoning is fair. This seems to list [most of the amines and its dissociations with some useful info](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/267544155_Dissociation_Constants_pKa_of_Tertiary_and_Cyclic_Amines_Structural_and_Temperature_Dependences) However don't forget any steric hindrance that could degrade the (alkyl contributed) electrons releasing ability of tert-alkyl amine's `N` (because alkyl is larger than `H+` atom). Last but not least  solvation of ions is a must to consider due to the ability to form Hydrogen bonds. *a bit like catch 22 case* :P

Comment: Tri-(tert-butyl)amine has never been synthesized, so this is more of a theoretical study.

Comment: I learned that [Hünig's base](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N,N-Diisopropylethylamine) was the strongest one available. $\ce{N(tBu)3}$ is probably too crowded to even exist.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン Assuming if it exist. This question has actually been taken off an inorganic chemistry textbook. However, the answer was not provided. Therefore, I had to pose this question on this platform.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン A friend of mine mentions that steric hindrance only affects kinetics. Since I am only considering thermodynamics, in terms of equilibrium, can I safely put it out of the discussion? Or should I still consider it?